# MSMPI Application is unable to connect to the smpd manager

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mpi

I have the problem with the MSMPI from MS HPC Pack. I've get the error:
"Aborting: mpi application on *<*PCNAME> is unable to connect to the smpd manager on(null):50892 error 1722". I've tried to find an answer on microsoft website. No result. Replacing hpc pack from 2012 to 2008 does not give effect. thanks. the code is simple and, I'm sure, the problem lies not in it, but:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mpi.h>;
using namespace::std;
int myRank;
int numProcs;
char host[256];
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs); // number of processes involved in run
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank); // my process id: 0 <= myRank < numProcs
    gethostname(host, sizeof(host) / sizeof(host[0])); // machine we are running on
    cout << "Process " << myRank << " of " << numProcs << " is running on '" << host <<
        "'." << endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post gethostname code?

Comment: gethostname returns -1; WSAGetLastError returns 10093 which means WSANOTINITIALIZED; ok, lets call WSAStartup() -> "Aborting: mpi application on <PCNAME> is unable to connect to the smpd manager on(null):51261 error 1722".